# Anything else beside prepared statements before inserting user input into the database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

From my understanding so far the risks of inserting user input into the database are sql injections, witch prepared statements take care of, and from what i have read the data should not be altered before saving it into the database with functions like `htmlspecialchars()` this should be always used when echoing user input from the database on the page.

So if i have a query like this for example:

```
$var1 = $_POST['userInput1'];
$var1 = $_POST['userInput2'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName (Column1, Column2) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $var1);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $var2);
$stmt->execute();
```

Leaving validation aside is there anything else that needs to be done to this variables? Or from this point on, anything that the user enters in secure and can be stored?

*And on a side note should i use named placeholders instead of positional placeholders or this is just a preferential thing?*

Comment: minor nitpick: you should quote your query, and close the parentheses after it.

Comment: *"is there anything else that needs to be done to this variables?"* ... Nope - I think you're good, you could set the data type (e.g. `PDO::PARAM_INT`) if you want to be specific about it but...

Comment: This is my go-to reference for SQL Injection examples: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to the variables before using them as parameters for a prepared statment.

In fact, you *must not* do any escape_string or quoting or anything, because the backslashes or whatever will be inserted literally into your database.

You may also like the simpler usage of PDO. You don't need to use bindParam(), you can just pass an array of values to execute():

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName (Column1, Column2) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute([$var1, $var2]);
```

Regarding your question about named parameter placeholders:

It makes no difference, it's only a handy thing to help you write more readable code. You can still use the short form of passing an array of values:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName (Column1, Column2) VALUES (:col1, :col2)");
$stmt->execute(['col1'=>$var1, 'col2'=>$var2]);
```

It can be especially handy if you already have a hash array with the right key/value pairs—like your `$_POST` array. It's tempting to do the following:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName (Column1, Column2) VALUES (:userInput1, :userInput2)");
$stmt->execute($_POST);
```

But be careful about this, because you can't assume `$_POST` has *only* the fields you need. PDO will throw errors if you pass it an array with too many fields, or fields whose key names don't match your parameter placeholders. Anyone can therefore make a request that will cause your app to have errors.

Comment: One thing to note that write to db is fine this way but when echoing to the web site you should use `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Right, but that's to protect against XSS vulnerability, not SQL injection. These are number 1 and number 2 most common web app vulnerabilities!

Answer (score 0):

As i see you take Two input from user and put it in database,
in my opinion your data must pass at least this Two proccess .

1. Sanitize Data
2. Validate Data

As you see i write sanitize before validate this most important why?

```
//If You Want The Output after Validation and Sanitize "Hello" as string and 5 length chars. 
$userInput = "Hel<script></script>";
```

if you validate this first as string it will be valid string 
and then sanitize it will return back

```
$santize_data = "Hel";
```

My Mean Is You Must first sanitize Your Data Then Check It for Validation

Php Have Great built-in Function for [Sanitize with php](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)
and for validation [Validate with php](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

And You Have Some other tools like **casts** specific variable to specific type of data.

i hope this help !